# py2exe not making exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

I am following the tutorial for py2exe from this site http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial
this is the setup code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['script.py'])
```

when I type in cmd:

```
python setup.py install
```

I get this:

```
running install
running build
```

my script works fine and I even tried it for simple scripts such as

```
print "hello world"
```

I was able to use py2exe before without any problems but for some reason it stop working for me. I even tried to reinstall the module but it still won't do anything. Any idea's from those brilliant minds on stack overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build an exe, the command is:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```